# Python zip function returns too many values to unpack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a piece of code to transform some data frame. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
import datetime
from ipywidgets import interactive
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

parquet_file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smaanan/sev.en_commodities/main/random_deals.parq'

df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, engine='auto')

df['executed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['executed_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['first_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_delivery_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['last_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_delivery_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['last_trading_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_trading_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date

def split_tenor(row):
    start, year = row['new_window'].split(" ")
    if start == "Cal":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        year = int(year) + 1
    elif start == "Q1":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    elif start == "Q2":
        months = ["Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    elif start == "Q3":
        months = ["Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
    elif start == "Q4":
        months = ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    else:
        return row['new_window'], row['volume']

    if start == "Cal":
        split_vol = [row['volume']/12] * 3 + [row['volume']/4] * 3
    else:
        split_vol = [row['volume']/len(months)] * len(months)
    
    return [f"{m} {year}" for m in months], split_vol

def ConvtoQuarter(tenor, delivery):
  if tenor == "quarter":
    if delivery[:3] in ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']:
      return "Q1 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun']:
      return "Q2 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']:
      return "Q3 " + delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']:
      return "Q4 " + delivery[-2:]
  else:
      return delivery

                                             
filtered['new_window'] = df.apply(lambda x: ConvtoQuarter(x['tenor'], x['delivery_window']), axis=1)
                        
filtered["new_window"], filtered["new_volume"] = zip(*filtered[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
                
filtered = filtered.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
```

However, when I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 69>()
     65 split_1 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] < datecode].copy()
     67 split_2 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] >= datecode].copy()
---> 69 split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
     71 split_1 = split_1.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I do not know what this error means or how to avoid it, but that transformation is very important to my analysis, and without it the whole algorithm would be meaningless.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me fix this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `zip()` is returning a sequence of rows. You need to loop over them, assigning each column to the two variables.

Comment: @Barmar I thought `apply()` replaces the loop and is more efficient, wouldn't the loop take longer?

Comment: Apply loops and returns a new dataframe with all the results.

Comment: Never mind, now I see that you're trying to use `zip()` to pivot this into columns.

Comment: @Barmar Good. If you have an idea as to how to solve this please let me know.